# Solving system of nonlinear equations

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

Dear all,
Can anyone tell me all the algorithms that are available for finding all solutions of a system of nonlinear equations?

I am particularly interested in solving problems of the form:

X1=f1(X1,X2,...,Xn),
X2=f2(X1,X2,...,Xn),

...

Xn=fn(X1,X2,...,Xn),

where f1, f2,..., fn are nonlinear functions of their arguments and X1,X2,...,Xn are matrices.

Thanks,
Pat.

Comment: Is your system known to have a solution? That, in fact matters. What are the properties of $f_n$? That matters as well. Finally, do you want an algorithm that 
1. approximates a solution?
2. computes a solution?
3. approximates and proves that a solution exists.

  

Comment: "Can anyone tell me all the algorithms?" -- I strongly doubt it. This question strikes me as far too vague; see http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask I suspect that you don't want to consider all possible non-linear functions, but rather some subclass such as noncommutative polynomials...

Comment: Hi, 
Depending on the parameterization of f, the system may not have a solution.

In my case, f has the form fi(X1,X2,...,Xn)=inv(E0i+E1i*X1+...+Eni*Xn)*Hi, where E0i,...Eni and Hi are matrices.

There are potentially many ways in which one can get a solution to the system above. An obvious one is successive approximation. This method may fail to produce a solution even when a solution exists.

The ideal algorithm would characterize all possible solutions and show how to construct a particular solution.

Thanks,
Pat.

Comment: Look, if your nonlinear function is the square root function, how are you proposing to define the square root of a matrix?

Comment: @David: This problem is not solve in undergraduate numerical analysis texts, unless I am mistaken.

@Yemon: I do not have a square root function in my problem.

Comment: @Pat M: sorry, I missed the "all solutions" part.  For general nonlinear functions, I believe there is no such algorithm.

Comment: You might try asking on scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newton's method to solve $f(X)-X=0$: in your case, it means simply to study the recursively defined sequence
$$
X_{k+1}=f(X_k),\quad\text{along with a clever choice for $X_0$.}
$$
Of course here $X_k\in \mathbb R^n$. Assuming that you know that you have a solution
$f(Y)=Y$ at which $f'(Y)=0$. Then
$$
X_{k+1}-Y=f(X_{k})-f(Y)=\int_0^1(1-\theta)f''(Y+\theta(X_k-Y))d\theta (X_k-Y)^2
$$
so that assuming for instance that $f''$ is a bounded quadratic form (this could be only a local assumption) you get the so-called quadratic convergence to $Y$ (very fast convergence)
$$
\Vert X_{k+1}-Y\Vert\le C\Vert X_{k}-Y\Vert^2\Longrightarrow
\Vert X_{k}-Y\Vert\le C^{2^k-1}\Vert X_{0}-Y\Vert^{2^k}.
$$
To make only a local hypothesis, you must choose $X_0$ not too far from $Y$, which in practice is not so difficult to achieve.

On the other hand, to solve $\Phi(X)=0$, Newton's method requires only that at a solution $\Phi(Y)=0$ the differential $\Phi'(Y)$ is invertible: then your equation becomes
$$\Phi(X)=0\Longleftrightarrow
-\Phi'(Y)^{-1}\Phi(X)+X=X\Longleftrightarrow f(X)=X
$$
with $f(X)=-\Phi'(Y)^{-1}\Phi(X)+X$, $f(Y)=Y$, $f'(Y)=0$
and you are back to the previous setting.

A simple 1D example is
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{a}{2x},\quad\text{$a>0$, $x_{k+1}=f(x_k)$ converging to $\sqrt{a}$}
$$
an excellent algorithm to compute the square root, anyhow much faster than the high-school tedious method of extraction. Try your hand with $a=2$, you will see how accurate is the approximation of $\sqrt 2$for simply $k=2$, starting with $x_0=2$.

Comment: Hi Bazin, writing down the Newton for the problem I want to solve is rather complicated and expensive. In addition, the newton algorithm would be sensitive to the starting value and might deliver a different answer for every start value. The reason I am interested in an algorithm that could possibly give me all solutions is that I do not know in advance which solution I am computing.

Comment: This certainly won't give *all* solutions.

Comment: Yes: the method devised by Newton solves the equation $\Phi(X)=0$ at simple zeroes. Somehow these zeroes are stable by small perturbation and are much easier to find than the zeroes at which the differential is vanishing.